# Map `AltGr + [' to `å'

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I'm on a Norwegian keyboard and use `setxkbmap us` to code. Sometimes I communicate in Norwegian. This requires me to `setxkbmap no`. That is rather annoying. I would like to remap the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with another key to output the `å` character.

I've run `xev` and `å` has the byte code `c3a5` on key symbol 34, with the name 'aring'. I have remapped it in a keydef file as:

`keycode 34 = bracketleft braceleft aring Aring`

Then I ran `xmodmap ~/keydef`. For some reason whenever I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Map AltGr + [ to 'å'` <=!=> `whenever I press AltGr and ], nothing shows` - isn't this a bit confused? This looks like Linux, but which distro are you running? For Ubuntu: check the `Text entry` settings in the System Settings - switching keybord setttings should be one way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: @Hannu: I'm on mint 17. Also I mean for the code point to be inserted instead of actually remapping, upon pressing `AltGr + [`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> on the same modifier, see the output of

```
xmodmap -pm
```

However, you might like to read this [very useful archlinux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg) on keyboard configuration.  They suggest you would be better off doing, eg:

```
localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap us,no pc104 grp:caps_toggle
```

which creates a permanent setup which shifts between the 2 mappings `us` and `no` by pressing the caps lock key. Lots of other toggle keys are available. List them with:

```
grep "grp:.*toggle" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

The temporary setxkbmap equivalent is probably (not tested)

```
setxkbmap us,no pc104 '' grp:caps_toggle
```

but for those who dont read the comments, this is what finally worked for OP:

```
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,no -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Comment: Your answer did not work at all for some reason. I tried with other combinations to no avail.
What worked was the following `setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,no -option grp:alt_shift_toggle`.
That is the answer.
As a tangent: why don't tools consistently use -- for multi-character arguments? `gcc` and `find` also torture us with it.

Comment: @BourgondAries glad you persevered. I added your solution to my post in case others dont read far enough.